# Como utilizar o mod em C\C++?

Tags: c, c++

como faço para utilizar o a função MOD em C\C++?
`(N MOD 2) = 0` tenho que usar nesta linha do meu código.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O operador MOD é o `%`.

```
int n = 40;
if (n % 2 == 0) {
    cout << num << " é par";
}
```

---

Adicionalmente veja [`std::modulus`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/modulus/)

Comment: [Error] invalid operands to binary % (have 'float' and 'int') agora esta dando este erro poderia me explicar por que?

Comment: Por que o operador de resto da divisão é para operações com números inteiros e você está tentando fazer isso com um `float`. No caso de números flutuantes esse operador não faz sentido, a divisão de um `float` ou `double` não deixará restos (ainda que o resultado não seja preciso devido a forma como esses tipos funcionam, um `float` dividido por um `float` ou um `int` sempre tem resto `0`).

Comment: Veja [Why does modulus division (`%`) only work with integers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102948/why-does-modulus-division-only-work-with-integers) (SOE).

Comment: E quando o operando é menor que o operador, ex: 1 % 2 != 0?

Comment: @Robson, pense em `mod` como resto de uma divisão. Se você dividir um número `n` por um valor maior do que `n` a divisão inteira será `0` e P resto (módulo) será `n`.