# Como pegar todos os algarismos de uma variável em C?

Tags: c, funções

Eu tenho que fazer uma função que testa a divisibilidade por 3, retornar `true` se for divisível por 3. Caso contrário retornar `false`. Seguindo a regra : **Um número é divisível por 3 quando a soma dos seus algarismos for divisível por três.**

Tenho as seguintes variáveis :

```
int dividendo;
int divisor;
```

E tenho a seguinte função :

```
int divisibilidade3(int num);
```

Eu preciso separar os algarismos da variável `dividendo`, por exemplo, quando o usuário entrar com o divisor `3` eu irei chamar a função `divisibilidade3`e irei verificar se o digito final termina com 3, 6 ou 9.

Por exemplo, caso o usuário entre com o número `25848`, eu preciso quebrar este número em partes, sendo então : `2+5+8+4+8 = 27 e 2+7 = 9`, como é `9` o resultado final, então ele é divisível por 3.

A função deverá repetir o processo do somatório dos algarismos
dos resultados obtidos até que o somatório seja um número com um dígito. Se
este dígito for igual a 3, 6 ou 9, então o número original é divisível por 3.

Vou ter que seguir todas estas regras usando os critérios de divisibilidade. Se alguém puder me ajudar, fico grato.

Comment: Se entendi bem, você quer criar uma função que mostre que um numero informado é divisível por 3, você não pode usar o [mod](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11634/como-utilizar-o-mod-em-c-c)?

Comment: Posso usar mod até certo ponto, mas não posso verificar por exemplo se a%b == 0 para verificar se é divisível ou não. Tenho que seguir os critérios de divisibilidade.

Comment: O mod indica qual o resto da divisão, caso seja `0` quer dizer que o numero é divisível pelo valor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Divisibilidade( int num )
{
    int res = 0;

    while( num > 0 )
    {
        res += num % 10;
        num /= 10;
    }

    if(res > 9)
        return Divisibilidade( res );
    else
        return (res%3);
}


int main()
{
    int n;

    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%d", &n);

        printf("O numero %se divisivel.\n", !Divisibilidade(n) ? "" : "nao ");
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suspeito que o seu professor simplesmente imagine que você vai transformar o número em uma sequência de caracteres usando `snprintf()`, e depois iterar sobre a sequência:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
divisivel_por_3(int num) {
    char algs[12];
    char * ptr;

    // Se o número for negativo, troca o sinal (não afeta a divisibilidade)
    if (num < 0) num = -num;
    do {
        // Transforma o número em string
        if (snprintf(algs, sizeof(algs), "%d", num) < 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Falha na determinação dos algarismos de %d\n", num);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        // itera sobre os algarismos de num, substituindo-o
        // pela soma de seus próprios algarismos
        for (num = 0, ptr = algs; *ptr; ptr ++) {
            num += (*ptr) - '0'; // transforma o dígito ASCII '0'-'9' no inteiro 0-9
    } while (num >= 10);

    return (num == 3) || (num == 6) || (num == 9);
}
```